# jQuery animate works only once on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am having trouble animating my login box. When I first load the page the animation works perfectly. But after the first click the fadeIn works but the animation doesn't. Here is the code ...

```
$('#LoginShow').click(function(e){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'25px'}).fadeIn(500, 'swing');
});

$('.Black-Background-A').click(function(){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeOut(1000, 'swing');
    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'+=50px'}).fadeOut(500, 'swing');
});
```

The follwing part works with `fadeIn` every time but the second time it fires the `fadeIn` part works but not the `animate` part. Check it out on: http://www.farrislab.net

```
$('#LoginShow').click(function(e){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'25px'}).fadeIn(500, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: You should try resetting the `margin` to the `initial` value after `fadeOut`.

Comment: can you add demo of what you have now

Comment: If you want to see an example, visit: http://www.farrislab.net
Click on Register/Log in

Comment: Couldn't you just clone the original element state and replace it with the clone after you fadeout?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen can you show me a working example, if you don't mind. And to understand the situation more visit: http://www.farrislab.net
Click on the register button twice and see it for yourself.

Comment: Kindly check my answer. Although you've solved your issue, my answer might add something to the discussion.

Comment: I think it is an ease issue. The animation occurs before you can see it. Have a look at this list of eases : http://easings.net/ I think you will love to try some new easing anyway. The "elastic" ones could be cool for what you do.

Answer (score 0):

For me ,your original code is running , but you may made something wrong , try to get out you CSS file and check the function again

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>






<div style="border:1px solid black" id=LoginShow>LoginShow</div>




<div style="border:1px solid black" class=Black-Background-A>Black-Background-A</div>



<div style="border:1px solid black" id=Login>Login</div>





<script>

$('#LoginShow').click(function(e){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'25px'}).fadeIn(500, 'swing');
});

$('.Black-Background-A').click(function(){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeOut(1000, 'swing');
    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'+=50px'}).fadeOut(500, 'swing');
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out ...
I had to add a call back function in animate where the fadeOut is applied.
Here is the code ...

```
$('#LoginShow').click(function(){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeIn(500, 'swing');
    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'50px'}, 500, 'swing');
});

$('.Black-Background-A').click(function(){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeOut(500, 'swing');
    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'100px'}, 500, 'swing', function(){
        $('#Login').css('margin-top','0px');
    });
});
```

Thank you guys for your help :)

Comment: I didn't see you had it before posting something quite similar... Still, have a look about the easing lib. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was talking about in the comment when I said:

> You should try resetting the `margin` to the `initial` value after `fadeOut`.

**Example:**

```
$('.Black-Background-A').click(function(){

    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeOut(1000, 'swing');

    $("#Login").animate({marginTop:'+=50px'}).fadeOut(500, 'swing', function() {

        $('.Black-Background-A').css('display','initial');

        $(this).css('display', 'initial');
        $(this).css('margin-top', 'initial');

    });
});
```

Here I am simply resetting the altered CSS to their original state after the animation and fadeOut operations are complete. This will result in a much smoother transition.

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a fiddle that works.

It's a delay and easing issue.
Your fades lasts longer than your movement. And the easing 'linear' is preferable to "swing" for a fade (my opinion). Check for the CDN easing library I used ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/7chyzv2L/

```
$('#LoginShow').click(function(e){
    $("#Login").css({'margin-top':'0px'});
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeIn(500, 'easeOutCubic',function(){
    $("#Login").fadeIn(50, 'linear');
    $("#Login").animate({'margin-top':'25px'},500,'easeInCirc');

    });
});

$('.Black-Background-A').click(function(){
    $('.Black-Background-A').fadeOut(1000, 'easeInCubic');
    $("#Login").animate({'margin-top':'75px'},500,'easeOutCirc')
    $("#Login").fadeOut(500, 'linear');
});
```